# Change print output if database size reach near 2gb

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that gives me a nice printout of the MySQL database size. And I just thought it would be nicer if the font could change if the database size reached near 2GB.
I tried an if statement just above the last print, but then I just got a blank page.

```
<?php
function file_size_info($filesize) { 
    $bytes = array('KB', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'); # values are always displayed  
    if ($filesize < 1024) $filesize = 1; # in at least kilobytes. 
    for ($i = 0; $filesize > 1024; $i++) $filesize /= 1024; 
    $file_size_info['size'] = ceil($filesize); 
    $file_size_info['type'] = $bytes[$i]; 
    return $file_size_info; 
} 

$db_link = @mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass) 
or exit('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
$db = @mysql_select_db($db, $db_link) 
or exit('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error()); 
// Calculate DB size by adding table size + index size: 
$rows = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS"); 
$dbSize = 0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) { 
    $dbSize += $row['Data_length'] + $row['Index_length']; 
} 
//print "Database size is: $dbSize bytes<br />"; 
//print 'or<br />'; 
$dbSize = file_size_info($dbSize);
print "Database size is: {$dbSize['size']} {$dbSize['type']}"; 
?>
```

Does Any one know a way that I can get it to use `<font color="red"><b><blink></blink></b></font>` in this scenario?

Comment: just add another if statement for the needed size

Comment: @Alexander could you possibly give me an example on how that if statement would look?

Comment: Also, look edited answer, for different measurement units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this before your print statement:

```
$redAreaSize = "2048"
if ($dbSize['size'] > $redAreaSize) {
    $message = "Database size is: <font color='red'><b><blink>{$dbSize['size']} {$dbSize['type']} </blink></b></font>"
} else {
    $message = "Database size is: {$dbSize['size']} {$dbSize['type']} 
}
```

or, if you getting size in different units each time, you can you use next conditions in your if statement:

```
if (
    $dbSize['size'] > 2147483648 && $dbSize['type'] = 'B' || 
    $dbSize['size'] > 2097152 && $dbSize['type'] = 'KB' || 
    $dbSize['size'] > 2048 && $dbSize['type'] = 'MB' || 
    $dbSize['size'] > 2 && $dbSize['type'] = 'GB'
)
```

Comment: I now have it like this:
`$redAreaSize = "2027"; //2027 = 1.98GB
if ($dbSize > $redAreaSize) {
    $message = "Database size is:<font color='red'><b>{$dbSize['size']} {$dbSize['type']}</b></font>";
} else {
    $message = "Database size is:<font color='green'> {$dbSize['size']} {$dbSize['type']}</font>"; 
}

print $message;`

and it does not use the green message first, would it help if i somehow define `$message` to be that whole if statement?

Comment: substitute `if ($dbSize > $redAreaSize)` with `if ($dbSize['size'] > $redAreaSize)`

Comment: it works fine with `$redAreaSize = "2048"
if ($dbSize['size'] > $redAreaSize) {` it stays green when changing from KB to MB, so i can only assume that it would also work when changing into GB and then only turn red once 2048MB has been reached... maybe i should test... do you perhaps know of quick way to add 2gb worth of data into a mysql table? :)

Comment: that did not work for what i was looking for, for some reason it only added the data into a html table. I created php page to add about 20k entries into the database and ended up with 45k after a while, only reached 9MB... nevermind... the chance of this DB ever reaching 2GB is VERY VERY VERY slim. thanks again for your assistance.